# print names of files in folder from path in terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal, terminal.app

I was making a program and want to see all the items in a folder by giving it the path. my program uses the terminal so the commands are the same.

something along the lines of

echo "/Users/Danny/Desktop/saves"

save1.txt
save2.txt
save3.txt

that doesn't work that way but is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo` isn't the right command and I don't think you have the file path quite right. You'll need to specify an absolute or a relative path and it looks like you aren't doing either. A tilde (~) should suffice (e.g. `~/Users/Danny...`) for a relative path.

I think the command you're looking for is "ls" (that's an L in lowercase and not a 1 just for clarification).

- `ls "/Users/Danny/Desktop/saves"` will list the visible contents of the folder.
- `ls -al "/Users/Danny/Desktop/saves"` will list everything (including any hidden content).
- `ls -R "/Users/Danny/Desktop/saves"` will list files in subdirectories.